# Create a Shiny App to Upload a Stata Dataset and convert it into a SPSS File

Tags: r, shiny, download, shinyapps

I'm trying to  create a shiny app to let people upload a file, and the web page executes `rio::convert()` function, to transform a ".dta" file into a ".sav" file.

Is this possible?
How can you code the `UI` and `server`?

I made an attempt:

**ui.R**

```r
## -----
## ui.R
## -----

library(shiny)
library(markdown)

shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(

  sidebarPanel(fileInput('infile', label = "Datos en Stata (MÃ¡x. 30 MB)", buttonLabel = "Subir..."),
               downloadButton('downloadData', 'Bajar Base')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h3("Muestra de Datos"),
    tableOutput("contents")
    )
)))
```

**server.R**

```r
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30*1024^2)
## --------
## server.R
## --------

library(rio)
library(shiny)
library(tools)
library(foreign)

server <- function(input, output) {
    getData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$infile
    if (is.null(input$infile))
      return(NULL)
      rio::import(inFile$datapath)
  })
    getData_proc <- reactive({
      rio::export(file= "data.sav", x=getData())
      })
  output$contents <- renderTable(
    head(getData())
  )
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data", Sys.Date(), ".sav", sep="")
    },
    content = function(x) {
   #   rio::convert(input$infile$datapath, "mtcars.sav")
      #https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rio/versions/0.5.16/topics/export
      #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493392/how-to-fix-file-not-found-when-using-the-downloadhandler
      rio::export(getData(),file=x)
    }
)  
}
```

The webpage preliminary looks like [this](https://cursor2020.shinyapps.io/UploadFiles/). My main problem is that when I upload a file and try to download it, **the file that I can download a text file that when I download it shows the following error: "Failed - Server problem"**.

You can see this problem here:
[image: Downloads a text document, that ends with an error]

The log of the `shinyapps` webpage get the following message:

> Server version: 1.8.0.3-19  R version: 3.6.2  shiny version: 1.4.0
>
> rmarkdown version: (none)  LANG: es_MX.UTF-8  knitr version: (none)
>
> Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc2  jsonlite version: 1.6  httpuvversion: 1.5.2  htmltools version: 0.4.0  RJSONIO version: (none)
>
> Using jsonlite for JSON processing:  Starting R with process ID: '152'
>
> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:35337  Warning: Error in write_sav_:
>
> Writing failure: A provided name begins with an illegal character.
>
> [No stack trace available]:

Thanks in advance

Comment: This example can be of help https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/upload.html

Comment: Not sure if you already know that, but there's an app that does that already: https://gallery.shinyapps.io/rioweb/ and here is the code: https://github.com/lbraglia/rioweb

Comment: Thank you but none of these admit spss format as an output

Comment: As you may see, it only download spss files as text files

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I found that the problem in my app was in my dataset. This data contained many unformatted names, I resolved by using the function `clean_names` from `janitor` package. The corrected code is presented below:

```
## --------
## server.R
## --------

library(rio)
library(shiny)
library(tools)
library(foreign)
library(janitor)
library(lubridate)


server <- function(input, output) {
    getData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$infile
    if (is.null(input$infile))
      return(NULL)
    haven::read_dta(inFile$datapath, encoding = "latin1")
  })
    getData_proc <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$infile))
        return(NULL)
      janitor::clean_names(getData())
      #names(eso) <- gsub("-|\\.|\\/|'|\\[|\\]","",names(eso))
      #names(eso) <- gsub(" ","_",names(eso))
      })
  output$contents <- renderTable(
    head(getData_proc())
  )
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = paste0("data_",format(Sys.time(), '%Y_%m_%d'),"_",hour(Sys.time()),"_",minute(Sys.time()),".sav"),
    content = function(x) {
   #   getData_proc()
      #rio::convert(getData(), "mtcars.sav")
      #https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rio/versions/0.5.16/topics/export
      #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493392/how-to-fix-file-not-found-when-using-the-downloadhandler
      rio::export(getData_proc(),file=x)
    }
)

}
```